# How do you figure out the positional and chain isomer possibilities of a compound?

Tags: isomers

I need to figure out the chain and positional isomers of C4H7Cl. I am not looking for someone to directly give me the answer, I just want to know what steps are needed to be able to figure them out for a given compound.

This is different to my prior question. Here I am asking for the technique, not the direct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some examples of chain and positional isomers of C4H7Cl?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43997/what-are-some-examples-of-chain-and-positional-isomers-of-c4h7cl)

Comment: No. Please re-read.

Comment: You should have edited your old question, don't ask second time about the same topic.

Comment: Would it have reappeared on the main question page if I edited it?

Comment: It surely would.

Comment: It would need to be reopened before answer could be posted - editing would need to validate opening.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/constitutional-isomers-of-cis-1-2-dibromocyclopentane

Answer (score 2):

1. Is the parent hydrocarbon unbranched? That would be *n*-butane, $\ce{C4H10}$. Replacing one hydrogen atom by chlorine would lead to $\ce{C4H9Cl}$. Apparently, you're not having that!
2. Move a methyl group in *n*-butane, yielding 2-methylpropane, $\ce{C4H9}$. Here, replacing one hydrogen atom by chlorine gives $\ce{C4H8Cl}$. You're not having that either!
3. Does your target molecule have $\ce{C=C} $double bonds? Calculate the number of double bond equivalents in $\ce{C4H7Cl}$! I count one.

Work your way down from here.